# Retrofit заменяет POST на GET при отправке на сервер

Tags: android, api, post, get, retrofit

Я поймал очень странную проблему. При отправке POST запроса на сервер ретрофит заменяет его на GET

```
    @POST("api/v2/reviews/vote/{vote}/dislike/{dislike}")
Single<SimpleResponse> postReviewLike(@Path("vote") Integer vote, @Path("dislike") Integer dislike);
```

Это сам запрос. Ниже картинки в доказательство. Поставил дебаг точку в интерсепрете, что бы показать этот момент. Сервер ожидает POST, но ретрофит заменяет указанный мною POST на GET. Но с другими запросами, где я использую Field и тд - все отрабатывает нормально. (домены отличаются так как в интерсепрете подменяю базовый домен, если убрать интерсептер - ничего не меняется, ошибка остается)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, из-за чего может происходить это, и можно как-либо исправить?

Comment: Переведите, пж-та, вопрос на русский. ПО сути вопроса - у вас из-за этого не работает что-то? Возможно, дело в сервере, который делает редирект? У вас запросы на разные домены идут.

Comment: Сервер ожидает POST запрос, а приходит GET. Дело не в домене, я его подменяю в интерсептере, что бы в зависимости от настроет отправлять либо на тестовую либо на продовую базу. Там просто поставил точку, что бы показать, что почему то ретрофит подменил метод запроса, был POST - стал GET. Если убрать этот интерсептер - ничего не меняется, происходит то же самое, и самое странное - что остальные POST запросы отрабатывают нормально, только с этим возникла такая проблема, и не понимаю с чем связано, и как это вообще решить. Если делать POST запрос через постман - все отрабатывает хорошо.

Comment: Звучит крайне странно... Пробовали отправлять запрос через OkHttp? - его использует Retrofit для отправки запросов - так, наверное, можно будет убедиться, что проблема именно в Retrofit.  Коли так - покажите больше кода - как у OkHttp клиент настроен и как создаётся экземпляр ретрофита

Comment: Это однозначно из-за переадресации, только непонятно почему меняется метод (наверное из-за отсутствия тела запроса!?...) Я попробовал отправить на адрес со скриншота (`simplewine.ru`) - если нет слеша в конце, то он выдаёт редирект на адрес со слешем и вот здесь, видимо, и происходит недоразумение. В теории должно помочь такое указание в апи-интерфейсе: `@POST("api/v2/reviews/vote/{vote}/dislike/{dislike}/")`

Comment: Да, спасибо, добавление "/" решило проблему